# JS/CSS: how to animate a circle to pill shape?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Ok this is what I'm trying to achieve (ideally with JS/jQuery):
https://dribbble.com/shots/3445331-Expanding-Button

On hover, I need a circular div to expand into a pill shape so other buttons can pop in within it. When I click the "x" again, I need it to roll back to a circle shape.

I only know how to scale things with JS/jQuery. How can I do this? I can't find anything just searching with plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that "circle" in the beginning is a div with class `circle`, say with the following CSS:

```
.circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Then you could change that to the following:

```
.circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: width ease 0.3s;
}
```

So now the circle can animate width changes. We could define a "pill" width again with a class:

```
.pill {
    width: 300px;
}
```

And if you want to use jQuery to trigger the width change on a click, we can do the following: toggle the pill class on the circle div

```
$(".circle").on("click", function() {
    $(".circle").toggleClass("pill");
});
```

Of course to accomodate more buttons inside the "circle" div, you would use another selector for the click action, but you get the point :)

:edit:
Here's a fiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/6g0z3390/

:edit2:
I just realized you didn't want the change on click but on hover. In that case you could simply drop the JS and change the css from `.pill` to `.circle:hover` :)

Answer (score 5):

@mari Lai is right on. If you think of the containing div as a single rectangle with a changing width and consistent border radiuses then it's really pretty straight forward. (you can trigger this with jQuery/JS or simply hover/focus css)

Something like this...

```css
.pill { 
  width: 50px; 
  height: 50px; 
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #898989;
  transition: width .5s ease;
}
.pill:hover, .pill:focus { 
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pill">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of thinking that it is a circle to a pill shape, maybe try making it a square div, that changes the width to more of a rectangle on hover.

Then you would only have to make the border-radius rounded to look like a circle/pill shaped. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Kind of.. can you give an example?